# How to create columns dynamically in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

How to create columns dynamically in SQL Server?  I have created a table with the columns `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
a   b   c
--  --  --
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   5   6
```

I am reading data from Excel and inserting into the table.  If I get three columns from Excel, then there is no issue; but if I get more than three columns, I have to find out the new column, alter the table according to it, and insert its data like the example below.

```
a   b   c   D   E
--  --  --  --  --
1   2   3   
2   4   5   
3   5   6   
1   2   3   5   6
2   4   5   8   9
3   5   6   7   4
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use alter table column:

```
alter table tbl add column col varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't something like "dynamically create columns" in a existing table in MS SQL Server.

You will have to explicitly alter the table and add the new columns.